# how to delete rows if there are duplicate values on the same row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame called `overlaps`, with columns called `sp_a` and `sp_b`. If the same species is repeated in the same row, I want to delete the whole row. Any suggestions?

So I'm trying to delete row 3 and 4

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data (use `dput`) and expected output. Code examples are much easier to understand than prose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
overlaps[!duplicated(overlaps[c("sp_a","sp_b")]),]
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed. It doesn't quite work, unfortunately. This seemed to do it: overlaps <- subset(overlaps, sp_a != sp_b)

Comment: it doesn't remove any duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to delete rows where the value of `sp_a` is the same as the value of `sp_b`?

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

You can do this in one line with `filter` from the `dplyr` package. The below code filters the dataset, keeping only rows where `gear != carb` (that removes the first 2 rows):

```
head(mtcars) %>%
    dplyr::filter(gear != carb)

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
3 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
4 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```